query hangs for last batch of rows when using order by clause
We've noticed a problem that running a query with order by clause hangs the fetch of the last batch of rows for very long time. If we remove the order by clause, the problem dissapears.
begin
  for r in (select id from table where timestamp > to_date('2024.08.01') order by id desc) loop
    pragma_log(r.id);
  end loop;
end;

when counting the query results it shows there are 23011 rows, when running the code block, we can see that first 23k rows are logged in seconds, however the last batch of 11 rows, hangs for tens of minutes until being processed.
Same thing happens if you try to simply run the query itself, added to code block, just to be able to see how many rows are being processed.
It seems that rows are being processed in batches by 100 rows at the time, and the last batch hangs for a long time with when using order by clause.

where are you batching by 100 rows at a time? That's not visible in the code above.

I'm not sure where it's set. Could it be a database wide property? Or some property with which pl/sql developer opens a connection? I just see from the logs when code is executing that log count increases by 100

Batching is not something the database does. It's something the client may do.
